# How do I create a certificate within AppHarbor using a GoDaddy certificate

Tags: certificate, pfx, crt

I purchased a wildcard certificate from GoDaddy and I want to associate this certificate with a website on AppHarbor.

AppHarbor only allows me to upload a PFX certificate.  So, how do I convert a .CRT to a .PFX?

Answer (score 1):

If the contents of the .CRT files is a base-64 encoded certificate and it starts with `BEGIN CERTIFICATE`, you can dispense with the .pfx file and use keypair certificate entry method on AppHarbor.

Answer (score 0):

PFX is the private information exchange format (Windows calls them like this) and is actually the PKCS12 keystore.

All you have to do is import the certificate in your keystore that **already** has *your* private key and use that. You don't need to transform the certificate